# Chain rule for differentiation of distributions

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory

I am checking out an interesting paper regarding applying a chain rule for distributional derivatives. The paper is [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-108-03/S0002-9939-1990-0969514-3/S0002-9939-1990-0969514-3.pdf).

I would like to solve the given problem by this chain rule, but I am not sure how to proceed:

> Find the solution to the given derivative of the product
> $$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{(k)}$$

If I set $u=\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)$, and $\frac{du}{dx}=\cos{x}^{(m)}\cdot \delta(x) + \delta(x)^{(m)}\cos{x}$, that doesn't work out, since $m=0,1,2,....$.

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks

Comment: What prevents you to use the usual Leibniz rule, i.e. $$(fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)} \;?$$ Moreover, you can "cheat" by noticing that $\delta(x) \cos x \equiv \delta(x)$.

Comment: @Abezhiko I did this: 
$$\big(D^\alpha f,\phi\big)=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(f,D^{\alpha}\phi),$$ with $f(x)=cos{x}$, $\phi(x)=\delta(x)$,  and $\alpha=k $

$$\big(D^k(\cos{x},\delta(x))=-1^{k}\int\cos{x} D^{(k)}\delta(x)\text{d}x=\cos{x}D^{(k)}\delta(x)$$

$m=0$:

$$(f,\phi)=\cos{x}\delta(x)$$

$m=1$

$$(f',\phi)=\delta'(x)=0$$


$m=2$

$$(f'',\phi)=\delta''(x)=0$$

Hence, $$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{(k)}=0  \ \ \ \ \ m>0$$ and
$$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{(k)}=\cos{x}\delta(x)  \ \ \ \ \ m=0$$

How would the answer by Lebniz rule look like? Can you post a complete answer?

Comment: @echinodermata Apparently that answer is not correct.

Comment: The answer given there is correct.

Comment: @MikeEarnest no.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz After I updated the answer there to be more detailed, do you still think it is not correct? If so, what specifically is wrong with the proof?

Comment: @MikeEarnest you can go "further". Please check my solution, which is validated by my Pro in the related post.